# Can I turn an array in memory into the code representation of that array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not even entirely sure how to ask the question, but assuming I have an array in memory like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 18451
                    [1] => MDX
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 18450
                    [1] => NSC
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 18446
                    [1] => RL
                )
          )
)
```

Is there some existing functionality to turn it into the code version of that array? I have a # of arrays I need to do this for, nested to various degrees. So I imagine I want output something like

```
$arrayname[] = array(array('18451','MDX'),array('18450','NSC'),array('18446','RL'));
```

I can write something to do it, but I'd rather not recreate the wheel if there's an existing way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be all you need:

http://us.php.net/var_export

Answer (score 0):

manually loop through the array recursively and create a string like how you want.

Answer (score 0):

**[var_export](http://us.php.net/var_export)** could help you there i think. The other option would be looping through it manually :(